# Formatted output with MPI_File_write_at?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, mpi-io

I'm trying to write a parallel IO program with MPI, I'm required to write the data to the file with a format as: `02 03 04` in the file instead of `2 3 4`.

```
fprintf(fpOut,"%.2d ",var);
```

Would be the serial counterpart of what I'm trying to do. I've looked around but couldn't find any answers so far. Any idea on how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_IO` writes binary data (vs text/formatted data).

So if you really want to write in parallel, you can use an intermediate buffer, and then write it, for example

```
char buf[4];
sprintf(buf, "%.2d ", var);
MPI_File_write_at(buf, 3, MPI_CHAR, ...);
```

That being said, you might want to reconsider your workflow:

- one option is to start using binary data everywhere (and write in parallel)
- an other option is to write intermediate data in binary and in parallel, and finally post process it (not in parallel) to "convert" it into plain text.